# How can I fill odd-sized spaces with fiberglass insulation batts?

Tags: insulation

A good deal of the insulation batting in our crawlspace needs to be replaced. Some areas are completely bare. But the width between beams is about 44 inches, and I can't find any batting that's even close to that width. (The current insulation is that wide, but it's very old.) Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: 44"??? Where is your home and when was it built? Are you measuring the length and not the width?

Comment: Is there a reason you're committed to batted insulation?  Is using foam instead an option?

Comment: Also, how deep is this crawlspace?

Comment: The home is 1974. There is already faced, batted insulation held up by lateral, periodic thin wooden strips stapled to the beams. (but as noted, a lot's fallen because of moisture & time). There are no 2X6 joists as I've seen in other crawls, just 6x6 beams supporting the subfloor, and they're about 3.5' apart. Foam isn't an option because all the ducts and plumbing are down there, The height of the space is only about 18" which makes it all that much more challenging.

Comment: Hrm...is there a slab on the "floor" of the crawlspace already, or is it just dirt?

Comment: It's dirt covered with new 6 mil plastic, which was installed as part of a new perimeter drainage system and sump pump a few months ago.

Answer (score 1):

A "bib system" is often used in these scenarios. A mesh is stapled to the underside of the joists, and fiberglass is blown into each cavity.

If you really want to use batts you'll need to support them somehow. You could install strips across the voids and lay the batts on them. You'll need to use several rows and cut to fit.

Comment: You could still use a mesh, even chicken wire, stapling it into place after the batts are installed

Comment: I like the notion of this, at least using strips of it cut to length. Easier than staple gunning the slats. The crawl is >2,000 sq ft, so doing uninterrupted chicken wire would be daunting.